# Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - Count records by hour with a start and end time stamp

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to build a query that counts how many records there are in an hour.

My tablet has the following columns:

```
SessionID, Created, SessionStart, SessionEnd
```

The session time stamps contain a date and time. example: 2012-09-07 05:11:08.150

The goal of the query is to return for example a column called hour and a column called total where the total would be the sum of the records within the hour by start and end.

I do not know if this is possible or not.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Let us know when you get stuck.

Comment: I actually am stuck... I am learning SQL.

Comment: You must make a minimal effort by actually writing the SQL. Or at the least, if someone feels inclined, they could help you if you actually presented some sample data, and a desired result set.

Comment: @user3324389, Please see my answer below. If you need a modified result set, please provide additional info. My answer will probably be voted down by noob-haters, so please vote it up and let me work with you to get the answer you need. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will return Totals for each Session that is active during the beginning of each hour you have data for:

```
-- load test data; Sessions starting from 9-5 lasting up to 3 hours
declare @YourTable table
    (
    SessionID int identity(1,1),
    SessionStart datetime,
    SessionEnd datetime
    )
while (select count(*) from @YourTable) < 1000
    begin
        insert into @YourTable(SessionStart)
            values(dateadd(minute,round(rand()*480,0),'2014-03-24 09:00'))
    end
update @YourTable
    set SessionEnd = dateadd(minute,round(rand()*360,0),SessionStart)

-- create hour table based on min/max SessionStart/End values
declare @hour table(BoH datetime,EoH datetime) -- Begin of Hour, End of Hour
insert into @hour(BoH)
    select dateadd(hour,datediff(hour,0,min(SessionStart)),0) from @YourTable
while (select max(BoH) from @hour) < (select max(SessionEnd) from @YourTable)
    begin
        insert into @hour(BoH)
            select dateadd(hour,1,max(BoH)) from @hour
    end
update @hour
    set EoH = dateadd(hour,1,BoH)

-- return results for sessions active during each hour
select
    h.BoH [Hour],
    count(t.SessionID) Total
from @YourTable t
    inner join @hour h
        on t.SessionStart < h.EoH
        and t.SessionEnd >= h.BoH
group by 
    h.BoH
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps me get the idea of the logic

Comment: Please consider voting the answer up and selecting it as the answer to combat the inevitable noob-hater down votes. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh, and you are quite welcome! I am always happy to help those just starting out. I think this stuff is fun :)